# Is it possible through the Windows API to place a window on top of jump list windows?

Tags: winapi, z-order, jump-list, setforegroundwindow

I'd like to develop kind of an assistant which places message windows on the screen, e.g. to guide a user where to click.
I'd therefore want to put such a message window on top (regarding z-order) of jump lists (e.g. to demonstrate a mouse-click on 'Open New Window' within the Firefox taskbar menu).

Is there a way to do this?

I tried several Windows functions, such as `SetForegroundWindow`, `SetActiveWindow` and `SetWindowPos`, but didn't succeed so far.

Comment: _"but didn't succeed so far."_ - **How** did it not succeed? For example, _how were you using `SetWindowPos`_? Were you simply setting your window to be on-top of the jumplist windows - or did you also try setting the jumplist window _behind_ your window? Were you even able to manipulate the z-ordering of jumplist windows in the first place? What Windows OS versions are you targeting? (e.g. Windows 11's taskbar and jumplists are very different (in implementation) to Windows 10's, which also differ from Windows 7+Windows 8's...

Comment: I use `SetWindowPos(myWindow, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)`, which results in error 127. I'm on Windows 10. Haven't tried manipulating the z-order of jumplists before...

Comment: Here's something you might find useful: https://behind.flatspot.pictures/overlay-uwp-apps-without-code-signing/ - basically, `SetWindowPos` won't let you set an arbitrary hWnd to be on-top-of certain privileged other windows (like `explorer.exe`) because (since Windows 8), window z-order stacking is partitioned into "bands" - I believe this might be why you're unable to position your windows over `explorer.exe`'s jumplist windows. There are multiple solutions (e.g. signing+`uiAccess` - or getting your hands dirty with Ghidra...)

Comment: Specifically, it looks like jumplists are in the `ZBID_IMMERSIVE_MOGO` band - which means you'll need to load your DLL into `explorer.exe` and call `SetWindowBand` from there to move your window into (or over) the  `ZBID_IMMERSIVE_MOGO` band. See more details here: https://blog.adeltax.com/window-z-order-in-windows-10/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it, looks promising

Comment: Use the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` style creating the window, or set it using `SetWindowLongPtr` and `GWL_EXSTYLE`, to keep your window always on top even when inactive.